# Problems opening Spotify on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, spotify

I've just installed Spotify, and it doesn't open, just displays an error message. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Error message:

```
[1102/172855.962775:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: And the error message is ....

Comment: Can you...tell us what the error message says?

Comment: its not coming up now, i checked the box, send a message to ubuntu, do you know where i could find that message

Comment: Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T or by searching it) then type `spotify` then ENTER. Please select the error message in its entirety, right-click > copy then paste it here by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: spotify
[1102/172855.962775:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: First of all make sure the system is fully updated: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` then reboot and try again. Needless to say, [edit] and update your question accordingly. I may not be able to help as real life is calling.

Comment: You can file a bug report and try to upgrade your system as suggested by @MichaelBay , however, if that fails consider upgrading to a higher version of Ubuntu, 16.04 perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the issue with NSS version.

Try this one:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3
```

It works for me.